# Reliable `print(repr(context))` for Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-unicode

I am debugging a complex issue and need to see the content of structured variable named `context`. Attempt to print it with this code fails:

```
print(repr(context))
```

With error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xb6' in position
2336: character maps to <undefined>
```

What is the reliable way to print structured variables to the screen for debug in Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use built-in [`ascii`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii):

```
print(ascii(context))
```

It works similarly to `repr` in Python 2.

```
>>> ascii('\xb6')
"'\\xb6'"

>>> repr('\xb6')
"'¶'"
```

Comment: What should I replace my `print(repr(context))` with?